# @Published not emitting update in tests

Tags: swift, realm, combine

So I have this problem with a `@Published` realm result that is not updating in tests.

Basically what I am trying to do is, to test if a realm update is causing my ViewModel to update the ui. To do this I am subscribing to the published field.

This is the Test:

```swift
   func testListUpdate() {
       // when
       let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Wasn't updated.")

       _ = sut.$stocks
           .dropFirst()
           .sink { value in
               expectation.fulfill()
           }

       try! realm.write {
           realm.add(Stock(value: ["name": "Test3"]))
       }

       // then
       wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
   }
```

`sut` is the ViewModel which looks like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class StockListViewModel: ViewModelBase, ObservableObject {
    let stockRepository: StockRepository

    @Published var stocks: Results<Stock>

    init(stockRepository: StockRepository) {
        self.stockRepository = stockRepository

        stocks = stockRepository.all
            .sorted(byKeyPath: "createdAt", ascending: true)

        super.init(title: "StockList_title".localize())

        self.notificationTokens.append(
            stocks
                .observe({ change in
                    switch change {
                    case .update(let updated, _, _, _):
                        self.stocks = updated
                    default: break
                    }
                })
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, the viewmodel has as `@Published var stocks: Results.

In the initializer the stocks are set (this update is emitted by the `Publisher` successfully and tested in another case.

Then I assign a realm change listener to those stocks and when it updates, I set the stocks new (see in the `observe` closure). This update is really called, but the `sink` in the test never emits the update. Thus the test fails.

So my question is: Why is the `Publisher` emitting the initial value, but never the updated one?

Comment: Does the change notification get triggered? If you put a break point/print statement inside the `observe` closure, is it executed?

Comment: Also, you should be storing your subscription returned by `sink`, not throwing it away, otherwise it might get deallocated prematurely.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, the `observe` closure is executed.

Will try to store the subscription in a minute

Comment: @DávidPásztor Saving the subscription helped. Thank you! You can post it as an answer, I will approve it. I just answered it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Combine, you always need to keep a reference to the `AnyCancellable` representing your subscription - in your test case, returned by the `sink` call, since the subscription chain is only kept alive while the `AnyCancellable` is kept in memory. `Publisher`s only emit values when they have subscribers - so if you throw away the subscription, your `$stocks` `Publisher` will have no subscribers and hence it won't emit any values.

You are throwing away the subscription by throwing away the return value from `sink`.

```
_ = sut.$stocks
       .dropFirst()
       .sink
```

Instead, you need to store the return value on your test class as an instance property.

```
final class YourTestClass: XCTestCase {

    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?    

    func testListUpdate() {
       // when
       let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Wasn't updated.")

       cancellable = sut.$stocks
           .dropFirst()
           .sink { value in
               expectation.fulfill()
           }

       try! realm.write {
           realm.add(Stock(value: ["name": "Test3"]))
       }

       // then
       wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the subscription of the `Publisher` was not saved.

So the line

```swift
       _ = sut.$stocks
```

should be

```swift
       cancellable = sut.$stocks
```

where `cancellable` is a field of the testclass.